# TCP to external ip

Tags: c#, tcp

I am building a messaging app in C# using TCP.

It works at the moment, internal and external is fine. The problem is that I don't know how to send messages from the server to a client, if the client is part of an internal network.

If the clients are on the same network, and they are all using the same router, so same public ip, how can I send my message to the client I want?

Comment: What a client is connected to your server, then you have the *bi-directional tcp channel*, you can send anything to client.

Comment: @LB Thanks, I never thought of it like that, I'll just do some testing.

Comment: @BaliC that's basically how it almost always works

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "internal and external is fine". But as for your broader question: within the same LAN, the external IP address is irrelevant; server and client know each other by the _internal_ IP address. That said, generally server and client can even be on the same machine, because they are identified not just by the IP address, but also by the port #, which is practically guaranteed to be different between server and client.

Answer (score -1):

If you want send message to client then you have a several ways:

1. Use sockets
2. Image the client as server (start up on each client some service for access server to the clients)